# Passing two parameters to Javascript function

Tags: javascript

Really really silly question, but I can't get this to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/t4R46/

```
function showOne(parentid, childid){
alert(parentid);
alert(childid);
}

<a href="#" onClick=showOne('div1', 'div2')>91</a>
```

Basically I want two parameters to be passed to the function but I get:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Is there any smart site to verify javascripts in? The error reporting in ie Chrome leaves a bit to be desired.

/Patrik

Comment: Right click `->` Inspect element. The value of an HTML attribute cannot contain a space unless the value is in quotes.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4R46/1/

Comment: also your fiddle will fail because your js code is inside a onload callback, it has an option to change this on the left side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the attribute value:

```
<a href="#" onClick="showOne('div1', 'div2')">91</a>
<!--      here -----^   and here -----------^    -->
```

In HTML, an attribute value can only not have quotes if it doesn't have spaces (or a few other characters) in it. Since the value you want to set has a space in it, you need to put it in quotes.

> Is there any smart site to verify javascripts in? The error reporting in ie Chrome leaves a bit to be desired.

You're looking for "lint" tools. Probably the most famous lint tool for JavaScript is Crockford's [`jslint`](http://www.jslint.com/). But it is *heavily* influenced by his personal style and opinions, so there's an active fork called [`jshint`](http://www.jshint.com/) that's very popular. There are online and command-line versions of both. Some IDEs offer lint options as well, such as [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) from JetBrains.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Tried it but it did not work:
http://jsfiddle.net/t4R46/6/

Comment: @user3558914, as i mentioned in my comment above, your jsfiddle will still fail because of the onload option that is set for the fiddle

Comment: @user3558914: As Patrick has already told you in a comment on your question, you need to change the second drop-down on the left from "onload" to one of the "no wrap" options: http://jsfiddle.net/t4R46/7/ jsFiddle has a *very surprising* default setting that wraps all of your JavaScript code in `window.onload = function() { /*...your code here...*/ };` But functions called from `onXyz` attributes *must* be globals (that's one of the reasons not to use `onXyz` attributes). If your code is wrapped in a function, your function isn't global anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes will help.

```
<a href="#" onClick="showOne('div1', 'div2')">91</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tried it but it did not work: jsfiddle.net/t4R46/6

Answer (score 1):

The best tools are : [jshint](http://jshint.com), and [jslint](http://jslint.com)

Answer (score 1):

You are missin `"`

```
<a href="#" onClick="showOne('div1', 'div2')">91</a>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t4R46/5/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tried it but it did not work: jsfiddle.net/t4R46/6

Comment: did you tried my fiffle code in your own code.it will work cos in JSfiddle when i put the both html+js code together its working. it means may i am missing some jsfiddle stuff but code will work